# 1px linear-gradient disappears when zooming out on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm applying a linear-gradient 1px high on the bottom of an element.
When the browser zoom is set to 100% everything works perfectly.

If I reduce the zoom to 90%, the background is not visible anymore.

It happens only on Google Chrome... How can I fix it?

This is the styling (stylus):

```
.test
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red, red)
  background-size: 1px 1px
  background-position: bottom
  background-repeat: repeat-x
```

Here the demo:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/epLGep?editors=110

Comment: I'd guess that since Chrome rounds down it can't show an image that's less than 1px is height. Why not use a bottom border instead? Or perhaps a pseudo-element?

Comment: @Paulie_D it works on all the other browser so this must be a bug in Chrome.... I can't use pseudo-elements because I need to apply it to an `input`, and I can't use `border` because I need to use multiple-backgrounds to make an animation.

Comment: Different broswers have different rules about sub-pixel rounding. I believe Chrome always rounds down but otherwise..yep, could be a bug.

Comment: Just try `background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red 1px, transparent 1px)  background-position: bottom` alone (and remove all other `background-*` properties). This should work atleast upto 50% zoom on Chrome. It is only a workaround though and I can't explain why Chrome does what it does.

Comment: Thanks @Harry your workaround seems to work. I've opened an issue on the chromium bug tracker btw (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=zoom%20linear-gradient&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=551841&thanks=551841&ts=1446724733)

Comment: I would not mark it as correct because the workaround forces you to use the `to top` linear-gradient, so it can't work if your linear gradient needs to be horizontal (for example a dashed border or so)

Comment: background-size is rounded to the nearest integer. Setting it to  10px 1.7px solves the issue for zoom levels of 67%, and will make it 2px only at 125%

Comment: @vals thanks, but doing so, the browser that support half pixels will draw a 1.5px line